# Open Specific Tab in TabControl Upon ContextMenu Click

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I have a WPF application whose body consists of a tabcontrol with 3 tabs. I have added to the application a systemtray icon with a contextmenu that has 3 menu itens (1 for each tab). I would like to open the mainwindow of the application to a specific tab upon the respective contextmenu item button click.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to jump or navigate to a specific tab in a tab control upon a click event. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off you will have to Name your TabItem in your XAML.

```
<TabControl name="MyTab1">
    Items
</TabControl>
```

Once you have done that,  You can add an event handle for a click on your Menu Item in your System tray like so:

```
this.menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItem1_Click)
```

After that you will need to write the code for the event you just referenced like so:

```
private void menuItem1_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e) {
    // here is where we'll open the window with the specified tab.
    var newW  = new MyWindow();
    newW.Show();
    MyWindow.MyTab1.Focus();
    }
```

If you need help setting up a context menu for your NotifyIcon in the system tray: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.contextmenu.aspx has a great example.